# Firefox & G-Sync: Refresh rate drops down to 80FPS from 239FPS - NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, firefox, 22.04, framerate

Note: In the whole post, by refresh rate, I mean **the refresh rate the monitor has**. The problem: It goes down, lower than it should be, and that's only because the graphics card does not send more frames per second to the monitor. The monitor is fine, the graphics card is fine (tested on Windows), but the software / configuration is wrong.

For some reason the refresh rate drops down to 80 when Firefox's focused and G-Sync is turned on. Have a look:
[image]

It's easy to see that the refresh rate dropped down to 80 when I focused Firefox which is a maximized window (gsync *for every window* is turned on). I have never noticed a drop before, so it must have happened in some Firefox update. Definitely not a hardware issue.
The mouse looks really ugly when the refresh rate is thus low.

I'm using the propietary driver, NVIDIA G-Sync and VRR Control.

I've also noticed that the screen re-connects when there's no Firefox window open at all, and then I start Firefox.

When I turn off VRR Control I get weird flicker issues. The screen's brightness sometimes drops off for ~100ms multiple times. That's a known problem (Samsung software engineers failed, I don't recommend the Samsung Odyssey series).

On Windows everthing's fine?

*--- this is from earlier, I won't edit this. I didn't know Firefox was affected only there yet ---*

**Further research, I found out that G-Sync is dropping my frame rate. By turning G-Sync off, I achieved permanent 239FPS:**

```
1200 frames in 5.0 seconds = 239.966 FPS
1200 frames in 5.0 seconds = 239.960 FPS
1200 frames in 5.0 seconds = 239.962 FPS
1200 frames in 5.0 seconds = 239.958 FPS
1200 frames in 5.0 seconds = 239.960 FPS
```

*However I'd like to use G-Sync since it can avoid screen tearing without any lag.*

Using Ubuntu 22.04...

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 45%   48C    P0    31W / 125W |    449MiB /  6144MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      8575      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                194MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8999      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               67MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11678      G   /usr/bin/nextcloud                  1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13782      G   ...x-106.0b6/firefox/firefox      178MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     75261      G   telegram-desktop                    5MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There's no g-sync tag for my question :(

Comment: I'm seeing a refresh rate that is variable, but always above 60Hz. Are you playing Windows games using wine or some other kind of emulation? Of course emulated software is always going to run worse compared to the software it's designed for. For reference, all the TV shows and movies you watch have a frame rate of 30 FPS.  What you're calling a "bad" monitor at 60Hz is the overwhelming default. All things considered, you are achieving a top-tier refresh rate. Maybe your expectations are out of line, especially if you're running Windows software expecting stellar performance.

Comment: My advice, if you want to run Windows games at a very high refresh rate, is to use Windows. If you don't like being forced to use Windows, complain to the developers of the software that they need to develop a native Linux client. Preferably not a port, as ports also suffer worse performance compared to the original game, but still not usually as bad as running the software using compatibility layers and emulation.

Comment: @Nmath, my problem is not a game or something. My problem is that the refresh rate drops down to 80FPS (or, 80hz) if there's no vsync application in the foreground. For example, the refresh rate drops down to 80FPS for the whole system if Firefox is opened which was never a problem. It usually always was above 230FPS, but since the last week something happened on my system (driver update or something else, I don't know). Why is the refresh rate dropping down suddently?

Comment: I have edited my post and added something to the top.

Comment: @Nmath with refresh rate I mean the rate of images of the whole display (eg. ":0") that gets sent to the monitor. So, my 240hz monitor is useless at the moment when I am using Linux, because somehow it drops down if there's no vsync application focused.

Comment: I found out that the nvidia's G-Sync is the problem.

Comment: I found out that the actual problem is Firefox @Nmath, I hope you like my clarified post with all the new information.

Comment: I think you may be confused about what Gsync does-- it reduces the refresh rate of the display dynamically. That's the exact behavior that you're describing when it's turned on. So I see a non-issue here.

Comment: @Nmath The issue is Firefox. The refresh rate shouldn't drop because the browser is too slow. But yeah, I think "my issue" is fixed, or rather "the original issue".